# How to call php variable in anchor tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page where I call in the data from mysql into a table. I'm trying to create a situation where they can click on the date on the table and that will link them to another page. Here is the code that I'm working on

```
$q = "SELECT*FROM forum";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
if (mysqli_num_rows($r)>0)
{
    echo'<table><tr><th>Posted By</th>
    <th>Subject</th><th id="msg">Message</th></tr>';
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo'<tr>
        <td>'.$row['first_name'].''.$row['last_name'].'<br>
                                    '.$row['post_date'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['subject'].'</td><td>'.$row['message'].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
else
{echo '<p>There are currently no messages.</p>';}
```

I'm trying to put anchor tags on this code

```
 '.$row['post_date'].'
```

I tried this

```
 <a href="edit.php">'.$row['post_date'].'</a>
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a href="edit.php"><?php echo $row['post_date']; ?></a>
```

Or the shorter variant:

```
<a href="edit.php"><?= $row['post_date']; ?></a>
```

Comment: Good answer. Don't forget the semicolon.

Comment: thanks. But I tried your code but it doesn't work. can you check where I did it wrong

`<td>'.$row['first_name'].''.$row['last_name'].'<br>'.<a href="edit.php"><?php echo $row['post_date']; ?></a>.'</td>`

Comment: @MichaelVillajin echo '<td>' . $row['first_name'] . $row['last_name'] . '<br><a href="edit.php">' . $row['post_date'] . '</a></td>';